# SQL where column is not value in a one to one of a one to many relation

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to write a mysql query to select all rows of a table where the one to one relation column is 0 of a one to many relation. basicaly i want all leads where finished is not 1.

**My failing query**

```
SELECT * from `leads`
LEFT JOIN `call_lead` on `leads`.`id` = `call_lead`.`lead_id` 
LEFT JOIN `call_result_codes` ON `call_lead`.`call_result_code_id` = `call_result_codes`.`id` 
AND `call_result_codes`.`finished` in (0) group by `leads`.`id`
```

This fails and still returns all leads even if they have a code with finished 1.

Expected output would be

lead with id 12 and lead with id 2.

**Table leads**

```
_____________________
|id  | name          |
|2   | test name     |                
|8   | test name2    |
|12  | test name2    |
```

**Table call_lead**

```
_____________________________________________________
|id | lead_id | user_id | call_result_code_id |remark|
|22 | 8       | 1       | 0                   |test  |
|23 | 8       | 1       | 1                   |test  |
|24 | 2       | 1       | 0                   |test  |
```

**Table call_result_codes**

```
________________________________
|id | description   | finished | 
|0  | not answering | 0        |                 
|1  | not interested| 1        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM `leads`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `call_lead` on `leads`.`id` = `call_lead`.`lead_id` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `call_result_codes`
                 WHERE `call_lead`.`call_result_code_id` = `call_result_codes`.`id` 
                   AND `call_result_codes`.`finished` = 1)
```

I assumed by your expected output that you want those who doesn't have a record in call_results_codes too, so its enough that they don't have a record there with finished = 1.

Comment: Found a error now. When call_lead has one record for a lead with a result code not finished and one for finished for the same lead it still get returned.

Comment: @marsje I think your data is wrong, look at `call_result_code_id` in `call_lead` , it has values 1 and 2. And look on `call_result_codes` , it has ID 0 and 1. I think this is what causing this.

Comment: That was just a typing error in the dummy data edited it in the "real" database it is correct

Answer (score 0):

try this.
You have the finish column in the join condition. i put in where to find the result

```
SELECT * from `leads`
LEFT JOIN `call_lead` on `leads`.`id` = `call_lead`.`lead_id` 
LEFT JOIN `call_result_codes` ON `call_lead`.`call_result_code_id` = `call_result_codes`.`id` 
WHERE `call_result_codes`.`finished` = 0
group by `leads`.`id`
```